# Preguntas aleatorias de un array

Tags: javascript, html5, web

Tengo un test con un conjunto de preguntas-respuestas. Me gustaría que de un conjunto de 3 preguntas solamente se muestren 2 aleatoriamente.

Creo que el código que tengo que usar es el siguiente, pero no tengo idea dónde lo tengo que ubicar: `Math.floor(Math.random() * myQuestions.length)`

Este es el JS del quiero seleccionar las dos preguntas:

```
(function() {
function buildQuiz() {
  const output = [];

  myQuestions.forEach((currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {
    const answers = [];

    for (var letter in currentQuestion.answers) {
      answers.push(
        `<label>
    <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
    ${letter} :
    ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
  </label>`
      );
    }

    output.push(
      `<div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
<div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>`
    );
  });

  quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join("");
}
const quizContainer = document.getElementById("quiz");
const myQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the strongest?",
    answers: {
      a: "Superman",
      b: "The Terminator",
      c: "Waluigi, obviously"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "What is the best site ever created?",
    answers: {
      a: "SitePoint",
      b: "Simple Steps Code",
      c: "Trick question; they're both the best"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "Where is Waldo really?",
    answers: {
      a: "Antarctica",
      b: "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
      c: "Sitting in a tree",
      d: "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
  },

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias aleatoriamente remover del arreglo output 1 elemento. Usando `splice()`

```
 var indice = Math.floor(Math.random() * output.length);
 output.splice(indice, 1);
```

En terminos generales lo anterior podria repetirse para remover N elementos de un universo M.

En términos de eficiencia tal vez sea conveniente primero decidir qué preguntas irán y luego procesarlas en tu arreglo output.